# Android app terminates when screen orientation is changed

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-manifest

Please have a look at my .manifest ,although i have put

```
android:screenOrientation="sensor"
```

the moment i change my screen orientation the app will terminate (no crashing hence no log).
I have read and added the below syntax

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>
```

but still no change.

have a look at my .manifest and suggest me how to resolve the issue (currently i have removed the android:configchanges part.)

```
      package="com.mystictreegames.pagecurl"
      android:versionName="1.1" android:versionCode="2">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="4"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:excludeFromRecents="true" 
             android:screenOrientation="sensor" 
             android:name="AndroidPageCurlActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:screenOrientation="sensor" 
            android:label="@string/standalone_example" 
            android:name="StandaloneExample"></activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Your app does not terminate.  The current activity is destroyed and recreated. Android is designed to work that way.  You should write your code to deal with onCreate(), onPause() and onResume() properly.  There is plenty of documentation for this at developer.android.com. Only use android:confiChanges if you are prepared to handle all scenarios which will cause your activity to be recreated and truly understand what you are doing.

Comment: thanks simon for the info

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this,

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout"
```

Comment: Please do not promote this hack which even Google say should only be used as a last resort.  All it does is hide the bugs caused by not coding the activity life cycle callbacks correctly which will then show up in half a dozen other scenarios.  The correct answer is to fix the problems.

Comment: at Simon thanks for your sincere suggestions.
I am working on your suggestions though

Comment: Agree to @Simon's comment, this fix won't get `Resources` updated.